# Issue with regular expression on modrewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I am working with mod rewite

```
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z]+)$ $1.cfm
```

so `myurl.com/about.cfm` is rewritten as `myurl.com/about`

The problem I am having is with urls with underscores or dashes

```
myurl.com/another_one.cfm
```

These do not work I get a 404,

Answer (score 0):

Extends the allowed charset of the pattern.
It is important to put the dash at first position.

Try something like :

```
RewriteRule ^/?([-_a-z]+)$ $1.cfm
```